# Power saver turns display brighter. Shouldn't it be darker?

Tags: battery, screen, battery-life

When my battery is running low, the power saver turns on. When that happens, my display gets brighter. Shouldn't it be turning darker to reduce the power consumption? Is it normal to get brighter or not?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Power Settings and check for the Brightness level. Someone must have changed the default settings

Answer (score 1):

@Sam007: Unfortunately I lost my browser cookie so I can't accept an answer but that was it.

In the power saving settings the display brightness was set to 50%. I keep my phone on a lower level because I don't like a bright screen. When the power saver turned on, it actually made the display brighter than the normal level.

I changed the setting to 25%.

Thanks a lot!